# I don't see a way that

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Thursday, March 22, 2007 5:52 AM by CalifJim
>
> *rather than* shows a judgment. One choice is preferred over the other. It is better somehow.
> *instead of* merely expresses a replacement of one thing for another.
>
> I would *rather* have ice cream *than* apple pie because I like ice cream better.
>
> But if there weren't very much ice cream left, and I wanted to save some for tomorrow, I might have apple pie *instead* of ice cream tonight.
>
> I don't ***see a way*** that tangible vs. intangible has anything to do with it.

[Reference](https://www.google.co.kr/amp/s/www.englishforums.com/English/RatherThanVsInsteadOf/vbkrr/amp.htm)

---

I've looked up "***see***" and "***way***" in the dictionary, but I'm not sure what they mean respectively.

Comment: [see 2b: to perceive as a possibility](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/see); [way 4a: a manner or method of doing or happening](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/way)

Comment: @stangdon "2b" say "to suppose as a a possibility", but what you wrote is different from it.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, I mistyped it.  But the meaning is very similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stangdon commented, this sentence means to perceive as a possibility. In a typical situation, consider this dialogue.

- You: I heard about this nice restaurant, "Restaurante".
- Me:  I'd like to go, but *I don't see a way* that we could get through the traffic.
- You: Okay. Let's go to "Restauranta" instead.

The meaning of my response is "The traffic is too heavy for us to get to the restaurant." Have a good day!